# Android Sending GPS to a MySql Database every 2 hrs Programatically

Tags: android, mysql, rest, gps

Hi I have created an Android application that takes the location from the phone and stores it in a text file every 2 hrs. Im looking to send it to a MySQL database instead of saving it to a text file . I am probably doing it all wrong but just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.
Code for storing in text file below:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        File log = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"GPS.txt");
        try {
          BufferedWriter out=
              new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log.getAbsolutePath(),
                                                log.exists()));

          out.write(new Date().toString());
          out.write(" : ");`enter code here`

          Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
          Location loc=(Location)b.get(LocationPoller.EXTRA_LOCATION);
          String msg;

          if (loc==null) {
            loc=(Location)b.get(LocationPoller.EXTRA_LASTKNOWN);

            if (loc==null) {
              msg=intent.getStringExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_ERROR);
            }
            else {
              msg="TIMEOUT, lastKnown="+loc.toString();
            }
          }
          else {
            msg=loc.toString();
          }

          if (msg==null) {
            msg="Invalid broadcast received!";
          }

          out.write(msg);
          out.write("\n");
          out.close();
        } 
    `enter code here`}
```

Comment: Hi Im just looking for someone to point me in the direction of Instead of saving the gps to a text file how do i go about saving it to a database . Thanks

Comment: i recommend you another easy peasy thing look here: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database you want to write to is in your own Android device, then the tutorial in the answer provided by Chris Moore is the first thing you should read.

If you want to write to an external database, it is still the first thing you need to read to understand how the database system works in Android, but then have a look at this guide here - http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-12-2/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer i will have a look at that tutorial and guide now

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial to learn the basics of storing information in the android database.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
You should have a class for handling the database and build a data storage method passing it the information you currently send to the text file.  You should be able to preserve most of the logic you have now and simply add a call to open the database, store the record, and close the database.